# Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND] with transpiled TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I want to write a standalone TypeScript script that I can run with `node entry.js`.

- `npx tsx entry.ts` successfully outputs `This is foo!\nBye!`
- `tsc` is successful
- But `node entry.js` fails with the following error:

```
node:internal/process/esm_loader:48
      internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                                ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\source\flib\lib' imported from C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\source\flib\entry.js
Did you mean to import ../lib.js?
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)
    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:224:11)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:836:10)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1034:11)
    at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:375:12)
    at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:344:25)
    at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:220:38)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:85:39)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:84:36) {
  url: URL {},
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}

Node.js v20.6.0
```

I'm at a loss on how to get this working and need help.

This is how my setup looks:

```json
// package.json
{
    "name": "flib",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "main.js",
    "scripts": {
        "run": "npx tsx main.ts",
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "typescript": "^5.2.2"
    },
    "type": "module"
}
```

```
//tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2022",
        "module": "es2022",
        "sourceMap": true
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

```
// lib.ts
export function foo() {
    console.log("This is foo!")
}
```

```
// entry.ts
import { foo } from "./lib"

foo()

console.log("Bye!")
```